# Checked luggage procedures between Haneda and Narita airports

Tags: air-travel, check-in, jal

I bought tickets from Japan Airlines (JAL), the details as per below:

Day 1: From Penang to KL and change flight to Tokyo Narita
Day 15: From Osaka Itami to Tokyo Haneda, then fly from Tokyo Narita to KL and back to Penang.

My question is, after I checked in my luggage in Osaka Itami airport and fly to Haneda, do I still need to do luggage transfer between Haneda and Narita airports?

Comment: Unless they now offer checked-though, which from memory (and experience) they didn't before, you will have to check in again as you are transferring from a domestic flight to an International flight and at different airports.

Comment: There are direct flights from Osaka-Itami and Kansai to Narita, I suggest changing flights if you can to eliminate a lot of hassle. Alternatively, just take the Shinkansen back to Tokyo.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't find an official source for you, this usually reliable forum has a recent thread about [transit from narita to haneda](http://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0+132037) which states the negative:

> Or we must organize and pay for our transport and carry our luggage?
>
> Yes